# Direct X 11 Texturing FX file error X3004 undiclared identifier "input"

Tags: c++, directx, textures

I am trying to texture a cube but when i try to run the progam the fx file thows error X3004 undiclared identifier "input" but input is declared near the top so i don't understand whats going wrong. I have tried for 4 day's plz help.

This code includes diffuce lighting as well as texturing. i believe that output.tex=input.tex is the problem but im not sure.

```
Texture2D txDiffuse : register(t0);
SamplerState samLinear : register(s0);

float4 textureColour = txDiffuse.Sample(samLinear, input.Tex);

struct VS_INPUT
{

    float4 Pos : POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;

};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constant Buffer Variables
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register( b0 )
{
    matrix World;
    matrix View;
    matrix Projection;

    float4 DiffuseMtrl;
    float4 DiffuseLight;
    float3 LightVecW;

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Vertex Shader
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//guroud shading with diffuse lighting
VS_OUTPUT VS(float4 Pos : POSITION, float3 NormalL : NORMAL)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output = (VS_OUTPUT)0;

    output.Pos = mul(Pos, World);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, View);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, Projection);

    // Convert from local space to world space 
    // W component of vector is 0 as vectors cannot be translated
    float3 normalW = mul(float4(NormalL, 0.0f), World).xyz;
        normalW = normalize(normalW);

    // Compute Colour using Diffuse lighting only
    float diffuseAmount = max(dot(LightVecW, normalW), 0.0f);
    output.Color.rgb = diffuseAmount * (DiffuseMtrl * DiffuseLight).rgb;
    output.Color.a = DiffuseMtrl.a;

    return output;

    output.Tex = input.Tex;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Pixel Shader
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
float4 PS( VS_OUTPUT input ) : SV_Target
{
    return input.Color;
}
```

error
Framework.fx(12,53-57): error X3004: undeclared identifier 'input'

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to sample a texture (on line 4) outside of any function. Where do you expect this code to run, in the vertex shader (VS) or the pixel shader (PS)?

Remove line 4 and change your pixel shader to:

```
return txDiffuse.Sample(samLinear, input.Tex);
```

You seem to have some structures that aren't used at all (VSINPUT, PSINPUT). The last line of the vertex shader won't compile either because you're using "input.Tex" and the vertex shader has no variable called "input". If you're not going to use them, change the first line of the VS to:

```
VS_OUTPUT VS(float4 Pos : POSITION, float3 NormalL : NORMAL, float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0)
```

and the end of the shader to be:

```
output.Color.a = DiffuseMtrl.a;
output.Tex = Tex;   
return output;
```